# Как принудительно удалить файл, для которого открыт поток чтения

Tags: java, файлы

Я пытаюсь удалить файл для которого открыт поток чтения, но получаю ошибку:

```
File file = new File("D:\\Java\\file.txt");
new FileInputStream(file);
Files.delete(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
```

Ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\Java\file.txt: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
    at com.dugin.rostislav.Main.main(Main.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

---

Как удалить файл, для которого открыт поток чтения (и возможности закрыть поток — нет)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае, удалить заблокированный файл средствами Java вряд ли удастся (как с помощью стандартных средств, так и с помощью сторонних библиотек вроде Apache Commons IO).

В Вашем случае, можете попробовать явно вызвать GC:

```
File file = new File("1.txt");
new FileInputStream(file);
System.gc();
Files.delete(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
```

Однако не стоит сильно полагаться на явный вызов GC, так как он не запускает GC, а просто дает рекомендацию JVM, чтобы она запустила сборщик мусора, а вот запустит ли она его сразу после вызова – далеко не факт.